# Как исправить ошибку c тегами: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'?

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь добавит теги в приложение через shell

Есть созданные таски.

```js
>>> from tasks.models import TodoItem
>>> t = TodoItem.objects.get(pk=11)
>>> t.tags.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'
>>>
```

Может быть, ошибка синтаксиса в модели?

models.py

```js
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class TodoItem(models.Model):

    tags = TaggableManager(),

    PRIORITY_HIGH = 1
    PRIORITY_MEDIUM = 2
    PRIORITY_LOW = 3

    PRIORITY_CHOICES = [
        (PRIORITY_HIGH, "Высокий приоритет"),
        (PRIORITY_MEDIUM, "Средний приоритет"),
        (PRIORITY_LOW, "Низкий приоритет"),
    ]

    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField("выполнено", default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tasks")
    priority = models.IntegerField(
        "Приоритет", choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES, default=PRIORITY_MEDIUM
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description.lower()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created",)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tasks:details", args=[self.pk])

    class Widget(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Запятую уберите.

Comment: @ andreymal  не помогло. После запуска t.tags.all() в консоли: 'TodoItem' object has no attribute '_prefetched_objects_cache'
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'taggit_taggeditem_items' into field. Choices are: id, name, slug

Comment: @andreymal  Если запятую убрать и запустить локально, то django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
tasks.TodoItem.tags: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Tag', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: нечто похожее: https://github.com/pigmonkey/django-wishlist/issues/1

Comment: @gisolog   taggit добавлен в INSTALLED_APPS, но ошибка не исчезла при вызове t.tags.all()

Comment: @gisolog может как то добавить индекс при возвращении tuple? https://fooobar.com/questions/378102/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: @gisolog  или, может, ошибка из-за того, что в первом выполняется итерация t, который имеет единственный элемент >>> t = TodoItem.objects.get(pk=11) а потом вызывается all?

Comment: добавить индекс при возвращении tuple? - 1) не, по идее вам должен возвращаться объект TodoItem, а не tuple. и 2) выполняется итерация t.. - это не итерация, это именно получение объекта TodoItem, а так  - дальше все, вроде, правильно

Comment: добавлен в INSTALLED_APPS, но ошибка не исчезла. а Run ./manage.py migrate делали?...